# Updateable Priority Queue

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, priority-queue

I've implemented an updateable priority queue as a part of implementing some single-source-shortest-path algorithms (Dijkstra, BF). I'm relatively new to Python.

```
class UpdateableQueue:
    def __init__(self,iterable=None):
        self._heap = []
        self._entry_finder = {}
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self._entry_finder[item[0]] = item[1]
                heapq.heappush(self._heap,(item[1],item[0]))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self._entry_finder:
            return self._entry_finder[key]
        else:
            raise KeyError('Item not found in the priority queue')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._entry_finder)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._entry_finder

    def push(self, key,priority):
        self._entry_finder[key] = priority
        heapq.heappush(self._heap, (priority, key))

    def pop(self):
        if not self._heap:
            raise IndexError("The heap is empty")

        value,key = self._heap[0]
        while key not in self or self._entry_finder[key] != value:
            heapq.heappop(self._heap)
            if not self._heap:
                raise IndexError("The heap is empty")
            value,key = self._heap[0]

        value, key = heapq.heappop(self._heap)
        del self._entry_finder[key]
        return key,value
```

Edit: a simple test case example of the `UpdateableQueue`

```
from UpdateableQueue.UpdateableQueue import UpdateableQueue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initalizing empty queue
    queue = UpdateableQueue()
    # Inserting key=1,priority=4 element to the queue the heap is now of size 1, and the dict size 1
    queue.push(1,4)
    # editing key=1,priority=1 element to the queue the heap is now of size 2, and the dict size 1
    queue.push(1,1)
    # editing key=1,priority=2 element to the queue the heap is now of size 3, and the dict size 1
    queue.push(1,2)
    assert len(queue) == 1 # True
    assert 1 in queue # True
    # on pop we remove (key=1,value=1) from the heap and then pop out that value of (1,2), followed by
    # removing that key from the dict
    key, value = queue.pop()
    assert 1 not in queue #True
    assert key == 1 # True
    assert value == 2 # True
    # Inserting key=2,priority=5 element to the queue the heap is now of size 2, and the dict size 1
    queue.push(2,5)
    assert len(queue) == 1
    # We "clean" the remaining (1,4) element from the heap and return pop (2,5) as expected.
    key, value = queue.pop()
    assert key == 2  # True
    assert value == 5  # True
```

Comment: Could you also show this priority queue in action?

Comment: @dfhwze Ive added a simple code example to it, let me know if there's anything else I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, there's not much for me to review, but here are a couple improvements/changes I would make.

**Improvements**

- **Docstrings**: You should include a `docstring` at the beginning of every method/class/module you write. This will help any documentation catch what your code is supposed to accomplish.
- **If/Else**: If you return a value in the `if`, then you don't need an `else`. You should just put the `else` code after the `if`, instead of inside an `else`, like so:

```py
if key in self._entry_finder:
    return self._entry_finder[key]
else:
    raise KeyError('Item not found in the priority queue')
```

to

```py
if key in self._entry_finder:
    return self._entry_finder[key]
raise KeyError('Item not found in the priority queue')
```

**Updated Code**

```
class UpdateableQueue:
    """ An updateable priority queue class """
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self._heap = []
        self._entry_finder = {}
        if iterable:
            for item in iterable:
                self._entry_finder[item[0]] = item[1]
                heapq.heappush(self._heap, (item[1], item[0]))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        Returns the item with the specified key, if exists. Else,
        it raises a `KeyError` exception
        """
        if key in self._entry_finder:
            return self._entry_finder[key]
        raise KeyError('Item not found in the priority queue')

    def __len__(self):
        """ Returns the length of the queue """
        return len(self._entry_finder)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        """ Returns a boolean based on if the key is in the queue """
        return key in self._entry_finder

    def push(self, key, priority):
        """ Pushses a priority into the queue """
        self._entry_finder[key] = priority
        heapq.heappush(self._heap, (priority, key))

    def pop(self):
        """ Removes a priority from the queue """
        if not self._heap:
            raise IndexError("The heap is empty")

        value, key = self._heap[0]
        while key not in self or self._entry_finder[key] != value:
            heapq.heappop(self._heap)
            if not self._heap:
                raise IndexError("The heap is empty")
            value, key = self._heap[0]

        value, key = heapq.heappop(self._heap)
        del self._entry_finder[key]
        return key, value
```